# Understanding a url that references a CSS file in a SharePoint master page

Tags: css, asp.net, sharepoint, master-pages

For SharePoint, this is the entry you could put into your master page to link to a CSS file.

```
<SharePoint:CssRegistration
      name="&lt;% $SPUrl:~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/dir/file.css %&gt;"
      runat="server"
      after="SharepointCssFile"/>
```

Could someone please break down the pieces of this url?  I don't understand the following parts of it and how they work together:

`&lt;%` - I do know this means less than

$SPUrl:~sitecollection/ - Is this some kind of variable? What's `~` for?

`%&gt;` - I do know this means greater than

Comment: `&gt;` is greater than `>`, `&lt;` is less than `<`.

Comment: ASP.Net: Tilde `~` tells ASP.Net "from root" of asp.net Application..and the way it's written looks "wrong": `~/sitecollecttion/..` So `application root` -> `sitecollection` folder -> and so on...

Comment: What would be the correct way to write out this url if my file is located at `/sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/dir/file.css`?  Why is greater than and less than needed?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Sharepoint, but the `<%` and `%>` (Note the percent signs!) are command delimiters in ASP.NET, so this is some means of inserting a command. The `$SPURL` _may_ be a variable, then it will be replaced by the value of this variable to form the path.

Comment: I guess I should have cited the source of my question.  I'm trying to follow this blog post http://kogzee.wordpress.com/2013/08/07/style-sharepoint-2013-top-navigation-global-navigation-menu about customizing global navigation in SP.  Any idea where you can see the variable in his code or what his intentions were with that url?  These are all great comments.  I'm not sure how to give credit to just comments.. I thought they had to be an "answer".

Comment: If the comments helped you to reach a solution, you can post the solution as an answer yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[CssRegistration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.cssregistration(v=office.14).aspx) is just one of the many ways of referencing CSS files in 
SharePoint.

lower than (<) and greater than (>) obvious, and ~ refers to the root of the current web application.

CssRegistration is particularly interesting because you can use **After** to make sure your CSS is loaded after another CSS such as core.css

The real relevant parameter is name, which in this tag can be used with **SPURL**, which in turn can be used with **sitecollection** or **site**, to refer to the current sitecollection root, or just the current site/web.

Note that SPURL is only available on SharePoint Server, not Foundation.

To support Foundation you can use [ProjectProperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.projectproperty.aspx), which takes **Url** or **SiteUrl**.

So to wrap up, SPUrl is a [token](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms431831(v=office.15).aspx) available in SharePoint that we can use to specify a resource from a specific location, relative to the current page, web, site and others.